# Kotlin-Coroutines - How to have two blocking methods at the same time and return the value of the first that finishes?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two methods: `fun doStuff1() : String` and `fun doStuff2() : String`

I try to do the following with Kotlin-Coroutines:

Run `doStuff1()` and `doStuff2()` at the same time, while blocking the main thread, return the value of the method which finishes first and continue with the main thread. The method which has not finished yet should stop at this point.

I tried some stuff, but I didn't get anything to work... maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well if they are blocking they won't co-operate cancellation. For getting the value whichever finishes check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html and since they are blocking one thing it will do is that it'll dispose the later so that its result is garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you very much. This could work. It would be great if it's somehow possible without using experimental features...

Comment: Don't know any other approach sorry. One thing you can do is launch two different coroutines and then send the result value to a channel and then receive only one and once done just close the channel and remove resources, while checking in the sender side that if the channel is closed then donot send the next (second) value.